# Headset not working in OpenSUSE

Tags: configuration, audio, opensuse, hardware

When I plugin my headset into my computer, running OpenSUSE, I do not get any audio. The regular speakers work fine.

The reason this is happening, I think, is because it still tries to output through the speakers, which get muted as soon as a headset is plugged in.

How do I change the configuration so when I plugin my headset it switches output device to the headset?